# json encoding of avro union

Tags: java, json, avro

I have a union in my avro schema for favorite_number which could be a null or an int. When I json encode the object I get:

{"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": {"int": 7}, "favorite_color": null}

I am trying to get rid of the type indicator for the union, in this case the int, so that it becomes:

{"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "blue"}

avro schema:

```
{"name": "person", "type": "record",
           "fields": [
              {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
              {"name": "favorite_number", "type": ["null", "int"], "default": null},
              {"name": "favorite_color", "type": "string"}
           ]
   }
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You should show some code how did you do it to get help

Comment: Did you get how to resolve this?

Comment: did you get this solved? I have the same problem

Comment: I am trying to keep the type indicator in the output JSON. What did you do to have the type indicator? I use ```org.apache.avro.util.RandomData(schema, 1).iterator()``` to generate random data from avsc to JSON sample, but it does not include the type indicator

Answer (score 4):

Editing whole answer :)

It looks like it is not possible do it directly with the Avro API. There is a pull request pending for a while to support this for nullable types

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1582

EDITING:

Base on your comments, I found the same issue trying to serialize without data types, I ended up using toString function defined in https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.html#toString(java.lang.Object), The only cases where it does not work properly, is for schemas with circular references.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - can you please elaborate

Comment: thank you for you answer, but my question is different. It does not have to do with the avro schema but with the json serialization based on the avro schema. So when I have a union in my schema I want the serialized json based on the schema to not include the type information.                             `{"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": {"int": 7}, "favorite_color": null}

I am trying to get rid of the type indicator for the union, in this case the int, so that it becomes:

{"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "blue"}`

Comment: @eng007 hey, I also has the same problem, do you find the solution?

Comment: If you use Binary serialization by building a nested GenericRecord from your json, it will work as you wish. The problem is how the json serialization is different from the binary serialization of unions.

If you call the toString() method on a GenericRecord, what you get back is the json that you are looking for. A GenericRecord looks similar to a Map, in that you can recover the data from a GR though the get method.

The key is building a nested Generic Record from your json. Like traversing a nested Map. Each nested map is another GenericRecord.

Comment: As to extend limitations, `GenericData`'s `toString()` does not work properly for logicalType UUID as well, since it omits quotes delimiting its string representation, hence it breaks JSON syntax. Avro version 1.9.2 here.

Comment: How to do the same in C++?
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.2/api/cpp/html/classavro_1_1GenericRecord.html