# Encoding optional strings with AVRO

Tags: java, avro

I am using Avro version 1.10.2

I have the following schema, with `optionalField` as an optional JSON string:

```
{
  "namespace": "foo.bar",
  "name": "FooBar",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "optionalField",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the Avro Maven plugin for performing code generation.

However, when I encode an instance of this object using the following code:

```
FooBar fooBar = FooBar.newBuilder()
                .setOptionalField("value")
                .build();

Schema schema = fooBar.getSchema();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Encoder jsonEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, byteArrayOutputStream);
SpecificDatumWriter<Object> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);
writer.write(fooBar, jsonEncoder);
jsonEncoder.flush();

System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
```

The output is:

```
{"optionalField":{"string":"value"}}
```

instead of what I would expect:

```
{"optionalField":"value"}
```

As far as I can tell, nothing in the the [Avro specification](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html) seems to imply only records can be optional. Moreover, under Unions:

> Unions, as mentioned above, are represented using JSON arrays. For example, ["null", "string"] declares a schema which may be either a null or string.

Is my understanding correct and Avro really allows for optional string fields? Is this a bug? What am I missing?

Comment: I just found a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624137/json-encoding-of-avro-union. I will give it a try. In the meantime, I flagged the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct and Avro really allows for optional string fields?

Yes, Avro supports a union of `null` and `string`

> What am I missing?

The way the Avro JSON encoder works is different than you are expecting. As mentioned in https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding, a union is encoded with the type information as a dictionary rather than just the value. There is an outstanding issue in the Avro ticket tracker that asks for the format you are looking for, but it has not been resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1582